# The Meaning Behind the Cross Validation Score in Factor Analysis

Tags: cross-validation, python, scikit-learn, factor-analysis

In order to choose the best number of underlying factors for my data using factor analysis, I decided to use the tutorial outlined in [scikit-learn's documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_pca_vs_fa_model_selection.html).

Running `cross_val_score(fa, X)` outputs a score (usually a negative number). What is this score actually measuring? Any references with your answer would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/37043/the-meaning-behind-the-cross-validation-score-in-factor-analysis) thread on data science stack exchange where I asked the same question:

> FactorAnalysis performs a maximum likelihood estimate of the so-called loading matrix, the transformation of the latent variables to the observed ones, using expectation-maximization (EM).